# How make long press click in listView

Tags: android, listview

How to make a long press handler to open the menu? I have this adapter, and click listener:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    int selectionRowID = position;
    String selectedFileString = this.directoryEntries.get(selectionRowID);
    File clickedFile = new File(selectedFileString);
    if (clickedFile != null)
        this.go(clickedFile);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, this.directoryName);
this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

But, i dont know how make long listener. Help me, guys :(

add xml:

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:longClickable="true"

        android:layout_weight="2"

        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                                            />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `Activity` you have to override `onCreateContextMenu`

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

> Implement the onCreateContextMenu() method in your Activity or
>   Fragment. When the registered view receives a long-click event, the
>   system calls your onCreateContextMenu() method. This is where you
>   define the menu items, usually by inflating a menu resource.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion for your question on listview,

```
ListView lv;
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(AdapterView<?>, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Code to execute on long click
        }
});
```

Comment: i dont have Id ListView: 
            android:id="@id/android:list"

Comment: Then just add listView.setOnItemLongClickListener to your previous code.

Answer (score 0):

First enable reacts to long click events.

```
listview.setLongClickable(true);
```

Then

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.d("long clicked","position: " + pos);

                return true;
            }
        });
```